How should I organize code, if I want to request url parse from start_requests(), and also need to request to switch to next page
I am parsing a news website, start point main-url is a web page of list of news.
And I want to parse out each sub-url of news, and request these sub-url to get corresponding html. Then if the main-url still have next page, I will request to the next page. Here is my code:
    def parse(self, response):
        res_json = json.loads(response.text)
        if res_json['code'] == 200:
            news_list = page_info['list']
            next_page_num = page_info['nextPageNum']
            has_next = page_info['hasNext']
            for news in news_list:
                news_url = page_info['shareUrl']
                item['url'] = news_url
                yield response.follow(news_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_news_html, cb_kwargs=dict(item=item))

            if has_next is True:
                self.body = ('"pageNum":{}').format(next_page_num)
                url = 'https://api.abcd.com/www/newsList/channelNewsList'
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url,
                                     method='POST',
                                     body=self.body,
                                     callback=self.parse)

    def parse_news_html(self, response, item):
        item['page_html'] = response.text
        return item

However, in this manner, pipeline cannot get item, and main-url cannot switch to next page. As far as I know, a parse method could return a item, and or iterable of Requests. But cannot return two iterable of Requests. So how should I organize my code, so that I can return the item to pipeline and request next page.
Actually, I use requests.get() to query sub-url and return item can resolve the problem. I want to not depend on requests lib, because I think use the scrapy request itself to solve the problem is more "formal". is that correct?

"As far as I know, a parse method could return a item, and or iterable of Requests. But cannot return two iterable of Requests." this isn't correct, and you may also be confused by what is an iterable and what does yield do. I don't see problems in your code that you are describing.

Hi wRAR, what I expect is, I pass the item to pipelines and save to disk. But no file saved. And the spider always parse the first page, but not switch to next page. And if I use requests lib in parse method to get sub-url and save html to disk directly, it works. Another thing I observed is return or yield only worked in parse method. if I define another callback method, or another sub-method which called by parse method, and return or yield in those methods, it does not work. I think it's relate to the misunderstand I have for the iterable and yield. Could you please give some instructions.

Sounds like your selectors don't match anything, which should have been the first thing to check (well, the second thing after checking that the code you expect to run doesn't actually run).

create a [mre].

Appreciate the help from wRAR and Alexander.
Actually I didn't configure my pipeline in settings.py.
Thanks for your time.
Best,
KS
